# Permission Denied for cp command on Bitnami Nginx Docker Image

Tags: bash, docker, nginx, openshift, bitnami

I want to serve a static website using [Bitnami's Nginx base image](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-nginx). I have a multi-stage Dockerfile as follows:

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
COPY ./ /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY .npmrc .npmrc
RUN npm install && npm run build

# Production stage
FROM bitnami/nginx:1.16 as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage --chown=1001 /app/dist /app
COPY nginx.conf /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
COPY --chown=1001 entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +w /entrypoint.sh
CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

I use that `entrypoint.sh` to replace some file content with environment variables like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function join_by { local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; }

vars=$(env | grep VUE_APP_ | awk -F = '{print "$"$1}')
vars=$(join_by ' ' $vars)

for file in /app/js/app.*;
do
  ### T H I S   L I N E   T H R O W S   E R R O R   ###
  cp $file $file.tmpl 
  envsubst "$vars" < $file.tmpl > $file
  rm $file.tmpl
done

exec "$@"
```

On `cp` command it throws an error:

> cp: cannot create regular file '/app/js/app.042ea3b0.js.tmpl': Permission denied

As you see, I have copied both the dist files and the `entrypoint.sh` with `--chown=1001` (The default user in the Bitnami image), but no benefits.

Is it because the image folder `app` is [exposed by a volume by default](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-nginx#hosting-a-static-website)? How can I copy and modify that file I have moved into the image?

**P.S:** It runs in  an OpenShift environment.

Answer (score 0):

The Bitnami image performs some actions in the [postunpack.sh script](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-nginx/blob/master/1.16/debian-9/rootfs/postunpack.sh#L12), this script is called from the [*Dokerfile*](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-nginx/blob/master/1.16/debian-9/Dockerfile#L19). One of the actions perfomed by the script is related to configure the permissions due to the user running nginx is a non-root user. You can try implementing something similar with your needs.

Comment: So, like adding a `chmod -R g+rwX /app`before looping the files to copy?

Comment: Yes, `/app` and others like `/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf`, `/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs` or `/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp`

That is the point, the non-root user is `1001`, but this user belongs to the _root_ group and that is the key, configuring the directory with writable permissions for the _root_ group, the non-root user should be able to write in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a result of Openshift's behavior stated here:

[How can I enable an image to run as a set user ID?](https://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/how-can-i-enable-an-image-to-run-as-a-set-user-id.html):

> When an application is deployed it will run as a user ID unique to the project it is running in. This overrides the user ID which the application image defines it wants to be run as.
>
> ...
>   **The best solution is to build the application image so it can be run as an arbitrary user ID.**

So, instead of copying the files and modifying the owner of them (`chown`), the access levels (`chmod`) of the files must be set appropriately.